# How to make dynamic Javascript previous and next buttons?

Tags: javascript

I made a previous and next button function for a slide show, but after a few hours I found out that it is not dynamic.

For example if I press 3 times the next button (since theres 3 pictures yet) it resets to the first picture with an `if` statement, but if I doesnt end that cicle, for example if I press it two times (now stops at the third image and will go to the first if pressed once more) and press the previous button one time, it goes back to the second picture, and now if I press the next button (with a counter of 2) it resets it self (thats how I wrote it sadly) and instead of going from picture 2. to picture 3., it goes to the first one.

I'm not sure if I explained it well, but here is the code:

```
var nextArrow = document.getElementsByClassName("next");
var prevArrow = document.getElementsByClassName("prev");



pictures[0].style.display="block";

var n = 1;

nextArrow[0].onclick = function()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++)
    {
        pictures[i].style.display="none";
        pictures[n].style.display="block";
    }
    n++;
    if(n == pictures.length)
    {
        n = 0;
    }
}

var p = pictures.length -1;
prevArrow[0].onclick = function()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++)
    {
        pictures[i].style.display="none";
        pictures[p].style.display="block";
    }
    p--;
    if(p == -1)
    {
        p = pictures.length - 1;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="main-slideShow-div">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="my-slides">
                <img class="pic" src="images/animals/dog1.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="my-slides">
                <img class="pic" src="images/animals/dog2.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="my-slides">
                <img class="pic" src="images/animals/dog3.jpg">
        </div>
    
        <img class="prev" src="images/leftArrow.png" alt="leftArrow">
        <img class="next" src="images/rightArrow.png" alt="rightArrow">
        
        <div class="slider-div" style="text-align:center">
            <div id="lines" class="line"></div>
            <div id="lines2" class="line"></div>
            <div id="lines3" class="line"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="javascript1.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: #ffc;
    opacity: 0.85;
}

.next{
    padding: 18px 0px 18px 22px;
    border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
    right: 5px;
    margin-top: 190px;
    margin-right: 40%;
}

.prev{
    padding: 18px 22px 18px 0px;
    left: 5px;
    border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
    margin-top: +190px;
    margin-left: 40%;
}

.pic{
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

So what should I put to that `pictures[]` to make it more dynamic?
Or how can I solve this?

Comment: Plz include the HTML/CSS.

Comment: The post is updated, but I only included the code that is needed for that javascript to function.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```js
const nextArrow = document.querySelector(".next");
const prevArrow = document.querySelector(".prev");
const pictures = document.querySelectorAll(".my-slides");

let position = 0;
pictures[position].style.display = "block";

function hideIMG() {
  pictures[position].style.display = "block";
  for (let i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
    if (i !== position) pictures[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

function control() {
  if (position >= 0 && position < pictures.length) {
    hideIMG();
  } else if (position === pictures.length) {
    position = 0;
    hideIMG();
  } else {
    position = pictures.length - 1;
    hideIMG();
  }
}

nextArrow.addEventListener("click", () => {
  position++;
  control();
});

prevArrow.addEventListener("click", () => {
  position--;
  control();
});

// Auto slide
setInterval(function() {
  position++;
  control();
}, 3000);
```

```css
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #ffc;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

.next {
  padding: 18px 0px 18px 22px;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  right: 5px;
  margin-top: 190px;
  margin-right: 40%;
}

.prev {
  padding: 18px 22px 18px 0px;
  left: 5px;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
  margin-top: +190px;
  margin-left: 40%;
}

.pic {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.my-slides {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-slideShow-div">
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="my-slides">
      <img class="pic" src="https://source.unsplash.com/HXJkqHexaak/" />
    </div>

    <div class="my-slides">
      <img class="pic" src="https://source.unsplash.com/ZHOVv_E8xZc" />
    </div>

    <div class="my-slides">
      <img class="pic" src="https://source.unsplash.com/z-lNmXoXt-k" />
    </div>

    <img class="prev" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/glpn7.png" alt="leftArrow" />
    <img class="next" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NNaT.png" alt="rightArrow" />

    <div class="slider-div" style="text-align: center">
      <div id="lines" class="line"></div>
      <div id="lines2" class="line"></div>
      <div id="lines3" class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but I absolutely doesnt understand the code, (never seen/used code like that before) How could I fix my problem with the method I used? Or is that not possible?

Because now the automatic slideshow doesnt work + the lines (position indicator) under the pictures, are not working of course.

Comment: @Idontknowhowtocode I might be able to help you if you share the complete code.  The code is fairly simple you can simply read it line by line and you will understand it. Also, I used functions to follow DRY (Don't repeat yourself). Automatic slide can be added to this.

Comment: I can share it, but not here, maybe in private chat

Comment: @Idontknowhowtocode I have added 4 more lines, now it will slide every 3 seconds.

Comment: @Idontknowhowtocode Where are you going to share...

Comment: We could share here, if we comment a few more times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230201/discussion-between-idontknowhowtocode-and-manas-khandelwal).